# 404 not found - phpmyadmin/Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, phpmyadmin

Estou usando Ubuntu e instalei corretamente o LAMP.

Abro as aplicações em PHP no `localhost` tranquilamente, mas quando tento acessar o `localhost/phpmyadmin` ele me mostra um `erro 404 Not Found`.

Já vi vários tutorias que usa um `include` dentro dessa pasta `include etc/apache2/apache.conf` onde é incluído o caminho.

Da primeira vez deu certo, mas tive problemas com a senha do `phpmyadmin`. Formatei a máquina e o mesmo procedimento não dá o resultado.

Comment: Qual o caminho onde tem incluídos os dados? Tem verificado os permisos da pasta? Sería ótimo se você adiciona mais informação ao respeito na sua pergunta.

Comment: Será que seria a permissão ao phpmyadmin?

Comment: Assim, instalei o LAMP, dps instalei o phpmyadmin... sendo que quando que eu dou o comando `localhost` executa, aparece "its works", mas quando eu vou acessar o `phpmyadmin`  para mexer no banco de dados ele da um erro not found.

Answer (score 1):

É necessário que tu link a pasta de localização do phpmyadmin para a pasta onde está os arquivos do seu site que estão sendo executados pelo Apache. Para isso utilize esse comando no terminal `sudo ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin/ /var/www` supondo que seus arquivos do site e o diretorio de execução listado no apache seja o /var/www.

Comment: Deu certo aqui! Era problema no apache. Eu tinha que marca a opção, eu reconfigurei o phpmyadmin